# What's the etymology of the expression '맙소사 !'

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Apparently '맙소사!' means something like 'oh my God!'

Does it refer to 'God' literally? I thought the words for God was '신'. 
What's the etymology and usage of this expression?

Comment: No! It has nothing to do with God. You can say "하느님 맙소사!" as 'oh my god'. Have a nice day

Comment: [This](http://www.korean.go.kr/nkview/nknews/200406/71_1.html) is a link which gives a thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the [link from @droooze](http://www.korean.go.kr/nkview/nknews/200406/71_1.html) has a good bit of very interesting conjecture with a few references and certainly seems accurate from my vantage.

[image]

Highlighted there (highlighting mine) is the following summation:

> ‘맙소사’ 는 ‘신이여!그렇게 하지 마십시오!’란 뜻이다. 그러니 ‘오 마이 갓’ 보다는 더 구체적인 의미를 담고 있는 것이다.

which I translate to:

> `맙소사` means **"ghost (and/or heavenly being)! please don't do that!"** And as such, more so than `오 마이 갓`, `맙소사` has a definitive meaning.